# XCODE 7.3, Exporting to AD-HOC, Failed to compile bitcode

Tags: xcode, bitcode

When exporting an archive to AD-HOC, during the compile BITCODE phase, getting the following error:

```
An Error occurred during export

failed to compile bitcode for XXXX:
```

Any clues on how to figure out what is wrong and fix?

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck the "rebuild from bitcode" box, worked for me.

Comment: do you know what the "rebuild from bitcode" option does?  Is it trying to export debug symbols or something?

Comment: I'm also curious as to why this option changes the outcome. Anyone have any insights to offer?